# AWS SWF decision takes long time to go from scheduled to completed

Tags: amazon-swf

We are trying out `AWS SWF`, our decider. The activity is very simple, just make a decision based on the event, then call the API to do something. However, after running the decider and activity workers for a while, a few hours a day, we found the time it takes for a workflow to go from `DecisionTaskStarted` to `DecisionTaskCompleted` or `ActivityTaskStarted` to `ActivityTaskCompleted` can take up to 5 minutes plus. We were also seeing activity taking 30 minutes plus or more to go from started to completed when the activity execution (actual business logic) only takes 100ms to finish.

Where should I start looking into this problem or is this an expected behavior? The load of the system is pretty light.

Comment: Do timestamps on the events in the history correspond to your findings? Are you sure that your workers are not stuck on something? I would recommend enabling client side logging to see the actual time that call to the service happens.

Comment: yes the timestamps for the event match my findings basically, it's 5 mins apart

Comment: So it is client side issue. I would recommend more logging. Getting thread dump of the process while it is "stuck" on activity or decision execution could also help to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: so what I found was that swfClient `respondDecisionTaskCompleted` api call is taking longer and longer to return, still not too sure why it gets slower as the time goes.

Comment: Weird. Have you checked all the way down to the tcp connection? May be it is some sort of retry kicking in?

Comment: hmm...does aws sdk (javascript) implement retry internally for all their apis ? any idea

Comment: I don't know anything about javascript aws sdk. But I've never witnessed similar behavior in Java or Ruby.

Comment: i added logging for aws client, and seem like everytime a new wf execution is created for this type of wf, a `pollForDecisionTask` connection gets created and start polling request every 60 sec.

Comment: found the issue, the slowness was cause by having long poll request created on every wf execution. it was a bug on the swf client we use.